# How to describe heat transfer between two solid materials?

Tags: heat

A general equation for dealing with heat transfer between one material and a region of insulating material. I've seen basic heat transfer equations for one material, but I'd love to see an explanation of how to do two.

Comment: Also look at ["contact resistance"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_contact_conductance)!

Answer (score 2):

The one-dimensional heat equation for a solid can be written as:
$$ 
  \rho C_p\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}= -\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left( k\frac{\partial T}{\partial x} \right) +\sigma 
$$
where $\sigma$ is the source term and $ \dot q =-k\frac{\partial T}{\partial x}$ is the diffusive heat flux. At the boundary the temperature and the flux must be continuous (if we consider contact resistance negligible, otherwise a gap in temperature could be possible) that is:
$$T_1=T_2$$ $$\dot q_1=\dot q_2 $$

Comment: Are you certain that the temperature should be continuous across the interface between the two materials?  In the steady state, I agree that the heat flux must be continuous (as long as there are no other sources of energy around).  However, as written in my response here http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/52900/heat-transfer-between-two-surfaces/52981#52981 there is at least one example for which different thermal conductivities on either side of the interface leads to a discontinuity in temperature.

Comment: I fear your answer is wrong. Your example is pretty general, and since "natura non facit saltus" at least as long as we don't consider an atomic scale nor a contact resistance, I think, completely wrong. Notice also that you state that boundary condition is $T_0$ on both sides of the problem, which leads to a constant solution. Ergo your demonstration is at least misleading.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree.  See, for example, the addendum in my response.

Comment: I notice that in your last equation L is missing. But this is not the point. You have used fixed temperatures for both boundary condition, so the flux is not fixed. Can't it be that the flux is exactly $\frac{T_R-T_L}{L} \frac{k_b k_a}{k_a-k_b}$ ?

Comment: What do you think about it?

Comment: I think you're right about the point that the flux can have that special value, and in that case, I agree that the temperature is continuous at the interface.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can use [Fourier's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_conduction#Fourier.27s_law)
$$ 
  q = -k\frac{dT}{dx}
$$
with the appropriate boundary conditions between the two materials. The basic issue is that at the interface between the two materials, there is a jump discontinuity in the value of the thermal conductivity, and you have to take this into account in solving the equation.

I did a very detailed calculation in a related post [Heat transfer between two surfaces](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/52900/heat-transfer-between-two-surfaces/52981#52981) that you might find useful in this regard.

Also, if you want to actually calculate something about something in the real world, you may find [this list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_thermal_conductivities) of thermal conductivities useful.

**Addendum.** In response to comments below Lorenzo's response.

Consider two bars of length $L$ and of uniform (but unequal) thermal conductivities $k_a$ and $k_b$.  Let the heat flow $q_0>0$ be constant along the bars, then Fourier's Law shows that the temperatures $T_a$ and $T_b$ of bars $a$ and $b$ satisfy
$$
  T_a(x) = -\frac{q_0}{k_a} x + C_a, \qquad T_b(x) = - \frac{q_0}{k_b}x+C_b
$$
for some constants $C_a$ and $C_b$.  Now suppose that the left end of bar $a$ is located at $x=-L$ and the right end of bar $b$ is at $x=L$ so that they are joined at $x=0$.  Suppose additionally that the left end of bar $a$ is at temperature $T_L$ and the right end of bar $b$ is at $T_R$, then we have the boundary conditions
$$
  T_a(-L) = T_L, \qquad T_b(L) = T_R
$$
which tells us that
$$
  C_a = T_L -\frac{q_0}{k_a} L, \qquad C_b = T_R+\frac{q_0}{k_b}L
$$
So that
$$
  T_a(x) = T_L - \frac{q_0}{k_a}(x+L), \qquad T_b(x) = T_R -\frac{q_0}{k_b}(x-L)
$$
In particular, at $x=0$ we find
$$
  T_b(0)-T_a(0) = (T_R-T_L)+q_0\left(\frac{L}{k_a}-\frac{L}{k_b}\right)
$$
In particular, there is, in general a jump discontinuity in the temperature at the interface between the two materials unless the temperatures at which the ends of the bars are being kept are related by
$$
  T_R - T_L = q_0\left(\frac{L}{k_b}-\frac{L}{k_a}\right)
$$

Comment: This is only true of $q$ is assumed constant throughout the domain, which it won't be in most of the cases. And if it is, it can be calculated from your last equation.

Comment: @Nico Agreed.  If $q$ varies with position, then my argument certainly breaks down.